# hiding the corners of UIImageView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

i have a `UIImageView` inside a `UITableViewCell` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. I placed the image at (0,0) location in the rounded table cell. When i run the application, i found the `UIImageView` still shows its left corners. The Imageview inside the cell is not clipped. Can anyone have a solution without setting the corner radius of the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to do this is using layer mask and corner radius. Here is how:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame
                                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];
            // Create the shape layer and set its path
            CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            maskLayer.frame = frame;
            maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
            // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
            imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

assuming that `frame` is the frame of your imageview. And, don't forget `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. Good luck!

Comment: Then in path specify that -- `UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame
                                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerTopLeft
                                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];`

Comment: Fahri Azimov can we set color using fill color or stroke color to a views mask and is it possible to set alpha to the view?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I didn't try that myself, doing some search, you can find answers.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the cell's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES` and see if that gives you the desired results.